# How do I extract particular value based another another value?

Tags: c#, json, regex

so I want to be able to extract and ID based on whether that object has a particular property. I NEED this to be done via Regex. Here is an example of the JSON I am working with:

```
{
"workspaceid": ws01,
"data": {
    "workspacetitle": "My Workspace"
},
"collections": {
    "projects": [{
        "id": 01,
        "data": {
            "title": "My Project 01",
            "enddateperiod": "2020-02-20T23:59:59",
            "profilecomplete": true,
            "synced": false
        },
        "lists": {
            "projectcode": [{
                "id": pcodered,
                "data": {
                    "code": "myproject123",
                    "name": "OffshoreProject"
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "id": 02,
        "data": {
            "title": "My Project 02",
            "enddateperiod": "2020-02-20T23:59:59",
            "profilecomplete": false,
            "synced": false
        },
        "lists": {
            "projectcode": [{
                "id": pcodered,
                "data": {
                    "code": "myproject123",
                    "name": "OffshoreProject"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}}
```

So what I want to extract is the ID of the project whose profile is not complete ("profilecomplete":false). So in this case, I want to select Project 2's id (which is 02).

How can I do this via Regex? I've managed to remove all of the whitespace and new lines as well so the JSON is essentially all one long line. Would it be easier to extract the Regex like this? Either way, I could use some help on how to get this ID.

NOTE: The format of the JSON cannot change.

Comment: Why must you use Regex and not a JSON parser?

Comment: It's what I am told. Can you help?

Comment: Then it's a school assignment of some sort? Because there is no way this is the best route for doing this...

Comment: I get that, but the best route wasn't really what I was going for. Thanks to you all for at least considering my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works

```
/"id": ([^,]*?)(?=,[^{]*{[^}]*"profilecomplete": false)/
```

Explanations :

1. Read all these chars first *"id":[space]*
2. Then read in a group chars that aren't ","
3. And then a lookahead : you expect "," then chars that aren't "{", then "{"; and finally, before matching the closing "}", you want to read *"profilecomplete": false*

But I agree that a JSON parser would have been my preferred option!

Comment: Thank you, David! This helped a lot.